# Updating Nickname field in Android Contact DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update nickname of a contact but not able to do so.
Below is the code which I have written

```
ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();

String selectArgs1 = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? ";

String[] selectArgs2 = new String[]{ContactId, "vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname"};  

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectArgs1, selectArgs2)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME, nickname)
                    .build());  

ContentProviderResult [] cpResArr = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

 int j=cpResArr.length;

 System.out.println(j);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value is updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked, below is the piece of code which worked for me.

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, ContactId)
                    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Nickname.NAME, "Sister")
                    .withValue(Nickname.TYPE, Nickname.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    .withValue(Nickname.LABEL, "Sister")
                    .build());
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

We need to obtain builder object and than add it to arraylist before calling applybatch.

Refer the following link for further info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html